# Tensorflow convolution layer crashes with "failed to enqueue convolution on stream"

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm using convolution layer in tensorflow with 4GB memory GPU(GTX980)

before using convolution layer, everything worked fine but when I started to use convolutional layer, following error occurred

**failed to enqueue convolution on stream: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED**

I heard this issue is related with GPU memory

and I know single tensorflow OP can have maximum 2GB due to protobuf limitation but my network doesn't have any OP that is over 2GB so this can't be problem.

**question is**, my whole network size(weight matrix size) is even less when I use convolution layer but this error keep occur.

When I change batch size to really smaller number, no error occurs but SGD works poor in that kind of small batch size.

can this be solved using other frameworks like PyTorch? or can I still use Tensorflow to run batch size of 500000?

or is it related with small memory(4GB) GPU?

help me please I'm stuck.

**network summary**

1. one 1d-convolution layer
2. FC layers
3. regression layer

**data summary**

1. batch size = 500000
2. feature size = 15 (float)
3. placeholder size for input : 15(feature num) x 8(float64) x 500000(batch size) = 60MB

**model code**

as you can see, it's really small network

I tried with bigger network without convolution layer but it worked fine

```
class MyModel:

    def __init__(self, learning_rate, batch_size, neighbor, weight_decay = 0.9, huber_delta=0.3, keep_prob_lst=[]):
        """ hyperparameters """
        self.isConv = True
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.lr = learning_rate
        self.input_size = neighbor * 3
        self.output_size = 1
        self.neighbor = neighbor
        self.weight_decay = weight_decay
        self.conv1_size = 10
        self.layer1_size = 100
        self.layer2_size = 100
        self.huber_delta = huber_delta
        self.keep_prob_lst_val = keep_prob_lst
        self.global_step = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False, name='global_step')

    def _create_placeholders(self):
        """ define the placeholders for input and output """
        with tf.name_scope("data"):
            self.input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [self.batch_size, self.input_size], name='input')
            self.output = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape= [self.batch_size, self.output_size], name='output')

    def _create_weights(self):
        """ define weights. """
        # Assemble this part of the graph on the CPU. You can change it to GPU if you have GPU
        with tf.name_scope("weights"):

            self.conv_W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,1, self.conv1_size], stddev=0.01, mean=0.0, seed=0), name='conv_layer1_weight')
            self.conv_b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, self.conv1_size * self.neighbor]), name='conv_layer1_bias')

            self.W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.conv1_size * self.neighbor, self.layer1_size], stddev=0.01, mean=0.0, seed=0), name='layer1_weight')
            self.b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,self.layer1_size]), name='layer1_bias')

            self.W_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.layer1_size, self.layer2_size], stddev=0.01, mean=0.0, seed=0), name='layer2_weight')
            self.b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,self.layer2_size]), name='layer2_bias')

            self.W_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.layer2_size, self.output_size], stddev=0.01, mean=0.0, seed=0), name='layer_out_weight')
            self.b_out = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,self.output_size]), name='layer_out_bias')

    def _create_loss(self):
        """ define the inference + the loss function """
        with tf.name_scope("loss"):

            self.conv1_input = tf.reshape(self.input, [self.batch_size, self.neighbor*3, 1])
            self.conv1_output = tf.nn.conv1d(self.conv1_input, self.conv_W_1, 3, 'VALID')
            self.conv1_output_reshape = tf.reshape(self.conv1_output, [self.batch_size, -1]) + self.conv_b_1

            self.layer1_output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(self.conv1_output_reshape, self.W_1) + self.b_1)

            self.layer2_output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(self.layer1_output, self.W_2) + self.b_2)

            self.layer_out_output = tf.matmul(self.layer2_output, self.W_out) + self.b_out
            self.se = 0.5 * tf.square(self.layer_out_output - self.output, name='square')
            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(self.se)

    def _create_optimizer(self):
        """ define optimizer """
        self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.lr).minimize(self.loss,
                                                      global_step=self.global_step)


    def build_graph(self):
        """ Build the graph for our model """
        self._create_placeholders()
        self._create_weights()
        self._create_loss()
        self._create_optimizer()
        # self._create_summaries()
```

Comment: Many people have encountered this problem and is filed as an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5688) on TensorFlow. The best solution currently seems to be to reduce the batch size. In any case, a batch size of 500000 is extremely large. How much data do you have such that you can run significant steps in an epoch?

Comment: @jkschin I have about 60 million record in total. so It seems to me that it's not related with the input size(in bytes) but the size of record(instance number) when using convolution. am I correct? I think I really should use other framework

Comment: @jkschin I saw that issue. people are dealing with images (200x200x3) x batch_size so they have big input whereas I have smaller input(because of less features = 15)

Comment: It appears to be that case from the issue page on TensorFlow. You can change to another framework but I think you're fundamentally not doing SGD "correctly", if there can even be any correctness to it. With 60M records, 500K batch size does not make sense. The whole idea of SGD is to have some "noise" when taking each step, with 500K samples, you're taking a very precise step. You are also taking only 120 steps in an epoch. To draw a contrast, the classic MNIST example of 55K samples with batch size 100 works very well.

Comment: @jkschin thanks for your reply. My model is about regression and I tested with multiple batch sizes. It showed 500k batch size worked best(about 1% compared to whole training data). Isn't optimal batch size differ from problem to problem? after listening to you I start to think I might done something wrong. is there relationship between batch size and epoch number to finish training? for example smaller batch - more epochs needed or something?